# SonarQube upgrade 5.6.6 to 6.4 - csharp scan is a lot slower

Tags: c#, sonarqube

We have been using sonarqube for a while, in version 5.6 (then 5.6.6) as part of a teamcity build.
It used to take 4 minutes to run a full project scan for C#
We've upgraded to version 6.4 (and updated the plugin to version 6.0) and it now takes 30 minutes to do the same.
It is using the same quality profile.
Is there new settings to do between the sonar-csharp-plugin version 5.5 and 6.0 ?

Comment: Did you create a new folder while installing the latest SonarQube? See also [this](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/HOME/Frequently+Asked+Questions) how to trigger an ES-reindex. Also try to update the statistics of the database used.